# Entity Framework .Find with Where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have something like the following in my code:

```
      dbContext.Progs
               .Remove(dbContext.Progs.Find(pNum));
      dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I was not able to figure out how I can add a `where` clause to the `Find` statement.

Comment: `Find` assumes that you are searching for a single record via its Primary Key. Use `Where` (or `Single`, or `First` etc) if you want to search using other criteria.

Comment: in what version of entityframework you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `Find` method only searches by primary key. If you want to use a condition use `Single`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` instead.